# Smooth Scrolling Behaving Weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://codepen.io/pallavkeshari/pen/eyBmeZ

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var scrollLink = $('.scroll');

    scrollLink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 1000 );
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();

        scrollLink.each(function() {

            var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 20;

            if ( sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation ) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
        })

    })

})
```

Smooth Scrolling is behaving very awkwardly. While going from "Home" to any other part of the page is working pretty fine, but when going from say "Resume" to "Projects" it is not working out.

Comment: Whay are you linking to a codepen for an error in this code when this code is not in the codepen?

Comment: yeah that codepen is not relevant

Comment: Updated :  Sorry , pls have a look once :)

Comment: Looks like offset().top is returning a negative value occasionally...

Comment: Solved !! Overflow-x :hidden and smooth scrolling just don't work together :)))